# My array is not loading pictures to the html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I believe I have this coded correctly, but I'm not getting the image to show up.

Here is the array of questions, answers and the image:

```
var questions = [

question:"Where should choking victims place their hands to indicate to others that they need help?",

choices:["A: Over the eyes", "B: Around the throat", "C: On the knees", "D: On the hips"],
correctAnswer:"B: Around the throat",

image:"<img: src='../assets/images/jeopardy.png' class='cashMoney'>"]
```

Here is how 
I'm calling the image:

```
function playerWin() {
    var image = questions[questionTracker].image;
    $("#gameShow").html(image);
    $("#gameShow").html("<p>You got it right!</p>");
}
```

I also tried appending the image to a Div through its own function

```
function displayImage() {
    var image = questions[questionTracker].image;
    $("#gameShow").append("<images>");
}
```

The image should show up with the

tag, but it does not.

Very new to all this. Any help greatly appreciated!
Sorry If I didn't format the question correctly. It looks fine on the editor but loses the indentation when I post. :/

Comment: Why do you have two B choices?

Comment: It should be `<img src='...` not `<img: src='...`. And you should be doing `$("#gameShow").append(image);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image isn't working because of the invalid HTML:

```
<img src: '...'>
```

There shouldn't be a colon. Replace this line in your array:

```
image:"<img: src='../assets/images/jeopardy.png' class='cashMoney'>"]
```

With this line:

```
image:"<img src='../assets/images/jeopardy.png' class='cashMoney'>"];
```

And your problem will be fixed.

Comment: Please don't post answers only pointing out a typographical issue or a missing character. Such answers are unlikely to help future visitors since they are specific to OP's code. Instead, flag or vote to close the question as off-topic as per the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Of course, my bad.

Comment: God I feel so stupid. Thank you

Comment: No problem whatsoever. If my answer helped you, could you accept/upvote it for future reference?

Comment: sorry new to posting on here. Should I remove the post?

Comment: No, you don't have to. It's always good to keep it there for future reference, both for yourself and for others.

Comment: ok, thank you very much

Comment: Like I said, it's no problem.